# What would be the expected time to find all users passwords in UNIX using dicitionary attack?

Tags: cryptography, password-protection, salt, dictionary-attack

I was reading that the designers of UNIX password algorithm used a 12 bit salt to modify the E-table of the unix hashing function (the DES). 
Supposing i have a system with 2^(24) users?

Is that ever possible to user dictinary attack? and if so how long would it take? years??

I am really new on computer security

sorry editing: I am not sure what unit time i guess i have to assuming bytes per minute depending on my code?

**The reason I am asking is for a project where one of the questions states:
"Consider a system with 2^24 users. Assume that each user is asssigned a salt from a uniform random distribution and that anyone can read the password hashes and salt for users." WHat is expected time to find all users' passwords using dictionary attack?"**

thanks very much

Comment: depends on how many guesses you get per unit of time... your question is like if have to drive 1000 miles how long will it take.

Comment: but in short, no you wont ever in the length of your lifetime be able to guess even one password, if it isn't in your dictionary.

Comment: Make sense. I can have a huge dictionary file and It will be comparing all password for long time

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a homework question that is expecting a formula as an answer.  Way too many things unspecified.  In particular, a dictionary could be precomputed with all possible salts (2^12 = 4096, not that big) for one password.  If all 2^24 users used that same one password, then every password would be in the dictionary and the question is what is the expected time to do 2^24 lookups into a table of 4096.  On the other hand, if none of the users passwords are in the dictionary, then you will never find the password using a dictionary attack unless you stumble upon a hash collision.

Probably better asked on [**security.stackexchange.com**](https://security.stackexchange.com/)